# Search exact word with regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following function to search for exact words within a text, so far it does it well, but what would I do if I need to search for the word +40°C, this word gives me an error because of the + symbol at the beginning, another word that I could search for would be (X9-X10(Y1-Y2), note that it has parentheses and one of them is not closed, and so I need to look for it, I would appreciate your help.

```
function searchWordExact(text, word) {
        const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i');
        const coincidences = text.match(regex);
        return coincidences ? coincidences.index : false;
    }
const message = 'ammonia x+y liquid +40°C (X9-X10(Y1-Y2)';
console.log(searchWordExact(message,'+40°C'))
```

Comment: Why are you not using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)?

Comment: @mandy8055 perhaps due to the `\b`. However @Jorge that won't work anyway because in `liquid +40` **there is no word boundary before the `+`** (there is one between `+` and `4` though) because `+` is not a word character, so your regex won't work for this case anyway!

Comment: Some other search strings must be matched as whole words. So, as usual in this situation, adaptive word boundaries should be used, and the word must be escaped.